# Authentication on one site using the ASP.NET membership of another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

We have one site that uses ASP.NET Membership for its user accounts. Let's say this site is at `www.domain.com`.

We have another site, let's say at `www.domain.com/site2`, which already connects to the database of site #1 for other reasons. We'd like to implement a username/password login to site #2, and would like to use the existing login credentials for site #1, as site #1 is where they apply for permission to access various systems, etc.

I'm not trying to create a SSO kind of solution, where signing into one site signs you in to the other, which is what other questions have been about.

I would like them to be able to enter their username and password that they have on site #1, enter it on site #2 and it auths them to site #2.

Is this possible?

Web.config of site #1:

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate" validation="SHA1" validationKey="AutoGenerate" />
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="VTDB" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="8" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
         connectionStringName="VTDB" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="VTDB" 
         name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
         applicationName="/" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
....
```

Web.config of site #2:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="VTConnString" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate" validation="SHA1" validationKey="AutoGenerate" />
```

Where `VTConnString` points to site #1's database.

But when I call `Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password)` in site #2, it always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue:

I was missing `applicationName="/"` in site #2's web.config. Now that the `applicationName`s are set the same, it works correctly.